# Why cancancan don't let me to access some pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan

I'm trying to create simple QA forum. I use devise for authentication and decided to use cancancan for authorisation.

Ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
    def initialize(user)
        can :read, :all

        if user && user.role?(:admin)
            can :access, :rails_admin
            can :dashboard
            can :manage, :all
        elsif user && user.role?(:user)
            can :create, [Post, Comment]
            can :update, Post, user_id: user.id
            can :update, User, id: user.id
            can [:update, :destroy], Comment, user_id: user.id
        elsif user && user.role?(:moderator)
            can [:create, :update, :destroy], [Post, Comment]
        end
    end
end
```

posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def withtag
    if params[:tag]
      @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag]).order('created_at DESC')
      @tagname = params[:tag]
      @tag = Tag.find_by_name(params[:tag])
    end
  end

  def usernews
    @posts = []
    allPosts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    userTags = current_user.subscribed_tags.map(&:name)
    allPosts.each do |post|
      postTags = post.tag_list.split(',')
      userTags.each do |tag|
        if postTags.include?(tag)
          @posts.push(post)
          break
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def userposts
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = Post.where(user_id: @user.id).order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id

    if @post.save
     redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image, :tag_list)
    end
end
```

When I'm trying to get access to usernews and to see all new posts, that are tagged with tags, that I'm subscribed on, or to see all posts, that are created by some user I get an error, that says

> You are not authorized to access this page

It happens if User role is not admin and he can't

> :manage, :all

How can I fix it and give access to this pages for users and moderators without using :manage.

P.S.: could you also say me, am I using rails_admin right?

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
  config.authorize_with :cancan
end
```

Comment: You are not authorized to access this page is clearly say that you haven't give permission to access that page so. check you permission.

Comment: @P_M I understand it, but why? 
can :read, all 
Why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
    def initialize(user)
        if user
            can :access, :rails_admin
            can :dashboard
            if user.role == :admin
               can :manage, :all
            elsif user.role == :user
               can :create, [Post, Comment]
               can :update, Post, user_id: user.id
               can :update, User, id: user.id
               can [:update, :destroy], Comment, user_id: user.id
               can :read, :all 
            elsif user.role == :moderator
              can :read, :all 
              can [:create, :update, :destroy], [Post, Comment]
           end
       end
    end
end
```